# Is there a recaptcha component that I can use in my amp page?

Tags: html, recaptcha, amp-html

I am converting my page into Google amp page, the link for my page is given below.

https://ppcexpo.com/Contactus

I am using recaptcha control in this page that is created using https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js script. I want the same recaptcha functionality in Google AMP, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [amp-recaptcha-input](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-recaptcha-input/?format=websites) component

```
<script async custom-element="amp-recaptcha-input" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-recaptcha-input-0.1.js"></script>
```

Using:

```
<form amp-form-attributes-go-here>
  ...
  <amp-recaptcha-input layout="nodisplay" name="reCAPTCHA_body_key" data-sitekey=”reCAPTCHA_site_key" data-action="reCAPTCHA_example_action">
  </amp-recaptcha-input>
  ...
</form>
```